# Unity Maze script

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I'm doing a course and I'm stuck on a task.

the task is:

Change the script for creating the maze so that the length and width of the maze are no longer specified in the script, but can be set externally using variables. To keep the effort low, you can restrict the values ​​to even values—for example, 2, 4, or 20. Make sure the script can only use valid longitude and latitude values. If the values ​​are invalid, the script should be terminated with a message.
The script should automatically scale the floor to the appropriate size for the maze and generate the outer and inner walls. You have to position the first stone for the outer wall and the first stone for the inner wall parts depending on the size of the floor.

You can use the game objects from the example for the floor and the wall parts. You can set the entrance and exit for the labyrinth at fixed positions.
You can test whether your script is working correctly by looking at the created maze in the scene view from above. Remember that you will also need to change the loop used to create the inner wall pieces. The number of passes must be derived automatically from the length and width of the maze.
The script to be changed accordingly looks like this:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Labyrinth : MonoBehaviour 
{

    public Transform wallItem;
    public int countX;
    public int countZ;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () 
    {
        float sizeX;
        Vector3 position;

        if (wallItem == null) 
        {
            Debug.Log ("Es wurde kein Objekt übergeben");
            return;
        }

        float newPosX = wallItem.position.x;
        float newPosZ = wallItem.position.z;

        Transform myChild = wallItem.transform.GetChild (0);

        if (myChild == null) 
        {
            Debug.Log ("Es wurde kein untergeordnetes Objekt gefunden");
            return;
        }

        MeshFilter meshFilter = myChild.GetComponent<MeshFilter> ();
        if (meshFilter == null) 
        {
            Debug.Log ("Es wird ein Objekt mit Mesh benötigt");
            return;
        }
        Mesh mesh = meshFilter.mesh;
        Vector3 meshSize = mesh.bounds.size;
        Vector3 scale = myChild.transform.localScale;
        sizeX = meshSize.x * (scale.x);

        for (int runX = 0; runX < countX; runX++) 
        {
            for (int runZ = 0; runZ < countZ; runZ++) 
            {
                newPosX = wallItem.position.x + sizeX * runX;
                newPosZ = wallItem.position.z + sizeX * runZ;
                position = new Vector3 (newPosX, wallItem.position.y, newPosZ);
                Instantiate(wallItem, position, Quaternion.Euler(0, Random.Range(0, 4) * 90, 0));
            }
        }
    }
    
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () 
    {
        
    }
}
```

Comment: This code is C#?

Comment: yes it is c# >.<

Comment: And what is the problem/question?

Comment: I don't know how to implement that.